# \leqslant causes "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have the following line: `$0 \leqslant b \leqslant 1$`

I want to display `0 <= b <= 1`, but I get `Undefined control sequence`

thanks

Comment: Are you loading the `amssymb` package?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

do you want it like this way? `$0 \le b \le 1$`.
Otherwise load `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Answer (score 18):

You should use the `amssymb` package.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$0 \leqslant b \leqslant 1$
\end{document}
```