# Why am I getting an undefined control sequence?

Tags: errors

Sorry if this is very basic but I really cannot figure out why I am getting this error. I checked all my commands and they seem correct. I attached my attempt along with what I am supposed to be typesetting.Thanks! [image][image]

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code which we can use to reproduce the error. This should be in the form of a minimal but complete document and should be pasted as text into your question. Pictures of code are not really useful. The same for your error. Please paste it as text.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16592/leqslant-causes-undefined-control-sequence/16594 Looks like `\leqslant` is your problem. You're probably gonna want to load the `amssymb` package. If that doesn't solve your issue, then you must do as @cfr recommends, because we don't have enough information otherwise

Comment: However, the problem is that you have not defined `\leqslant`. Add `amssymb` which provides it.

Comment: Yes! I loaded the package and it worked, thank you!

Comment: How to read the error message: the top line is everything that was read at the time the error happened, the bottom line is what was not yet read. So you can see that TeX had read up to `\leqslant` when it got the error, and it hadn't yet read `\sqrt{y}` and onwards.