# What is wrong in the following latex math code?

Tags: equations, amsmath

```
$$
\left. \begin{array}{c}
    \frac{NR}{K}=50\\
    0<R\leqslant 35\\
    NR\geqslant 65\\
    N>0\\
    K=24\\
    NR\geqslant \text{600 }\left( an\,\,initial\,\,guess \right)\\
\end{array} \right\} \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
    K_{\min}=24\\
    N_{\min}=40\\
    R_{\max}=30\\
\end{array} \right. 
\\
\left. \begin{array}{c}
    R_U=\frac{NR}{I}\\
    R_D=\frac{NR}{J}\\
    K=I+J\\
\end{array} \right\} \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
    I=K-K\alpha =24-24\cdot \frac{1}{4}=18\\
    J=K\alpha =24\cdot \frac{1}{4}=6\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$
```

I have tried to debug this code for a long time. The editor keeps telling me there is an error "Undefined control sequence". Can anyone help me out find where the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: First of all: don't use `$$`.

Comment: Why? This is not an inline math equation.

Comment: Read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/156344) for why.

Comment: Thank you. I am reading it.

Comment: You need to load `amssymb`, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16592/121799

Comment: @marmot `amsmath` is also needed.

Comment: Instead of legacy font packages, I would personally recommend you use `unicode-math` when you can, and compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex`. You’ll get more symbols with more consistency than any combination of legacy LaTeX fonts can achieve. You’ll still need `amsmath` (or `mathtools`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LaTeX, you have to use packages to use some predefined commands, like `\leqslant`, `\geqslant` or `\text`. This is one of the main differences of LaTeX and MathJax. The first two commands require `amssymb`, while the last one needs `amsmath`. Btw, don't use `$$ $$` like in MathJax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\left. \begin{array}{c}
    \frac{NR}{K}=50\\
    0<R\leqslant 35\\
    NR\geqslant 65\\
    N>0\\
    K=24\\
    NR\geqslant \text{600 }\left( an\,\,initial\,\,guess \right)\\
\end{array} \right\} \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
    K_{\min}=24\\
    N_{\min}=40\\
    R_{\max}=30\\
\end{array} \right. 
\\
\left. \begin{array}{c}
    R_U=\frac{NR}{I}\\
    R_D=\frac{NR}{J}\\
    K=I+J\\
\end{array} \right\} \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
    I=K-K\alpha =24-24\cdot \frac{1}{4}=18\\
    J=K\alpha =24\cdot \frac{1}{4}=6\\
\end{array} \right. 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, why do you use `array` with `\left` and `\right`? The spacing is awful! Also, using either `$$` or `\[ \]` won't let you have line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left.\begin{aligned}
\tfrac{NR}{K}=50\\
0<R\leqslant 35\\
NR\geqslant 65\\
N>0\\
K=24\\
NR\geqslant600\text{ (an initial guess)}
\end{aligned}\right\}&\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
    R_U=\frac{NR}{I}\\
    R_D=\frac{NR}{J}\\
    K=I+J
\end{cases}\\
\left.\begin{aligned}
    R_U=\tfrac{NR}{I}\\
    R_D=\tfrac{NR}{J}\\
    K=I+J
\end{aligned}\right\}&\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
    I=K-K\alpha =24-24\cdot \frac{1}{4}=18\\
    J=K\alpha =24\cdot \frac{1}{4}=6
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]